# Is this phrase right?

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

'if no unless, just do it now'. I read it on a diary from a non-native speaker. I know what he wanna express, but I feel that the phrase ' if no unless' is wrong in English grammar. What do you think of it?

Comment: I advise you to avoid forms like *wanna*, *hafta*, *gonna* in writing, unless you are employing them ironically. These are 'eye-dialect' written forms employed not to reflect speech accurately but to imply that the speaker's diction is substandard: they suggest that the speaker "would use a vulgar pronunciation if there were one" and "is at the level of ignorance where one misspells in this fashion, hence mispronounces as well"--Dwight Bollinger,  "Visual Morphemes", Language, 22 (4):337, quoted in [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect)

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "If no unless" is unheard-of; it doesn't sound grammatical.

However, you can use the phrase "Not unless" (=only if) as follows:

Not unless (it's) necessary, just do it now.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "if no unless, just do it now" is a meaningless string of words in English.  In fact it is hard for me to even guess what this person means.  However, I think the person wants to convey the idea: "If it's not a problem [if there are no extraordinary circumstances], just do it now."